# What variety is this tomato with long, milky green branches?

Tags: identification, tomatoes

I planted black krim tomato seeds and one of them came out like this:

[image: unidentified tomato]

[image: Picture of flower]
[image: Closer view of stem]

Other black krim plants are very different. This has rounded leaves, long branches and is somehow milky green color. Does anyone know what it could be? Thank you!

Comment: do you know what the fruit looks like?

Comment: I do not know the shape of a fruit but here is a picture of flowers: https://imgur.com/a/KL1OP19

Comment: Welcome Bulldozer! Thanks for this great question! I changed the title because identification questions need as many details as possible to get good answers. I also brought your pictures in from off-site so they're all visible here. We hope to see you often!

Comment: @Sue Thank you very much! I see there is a great community here. I hope to provide some good answers in the future too even though I am more of a novice gardener.

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid with over 20k tomato breeds and striking similarities among many of them (with crosses possible), there's not enough information for others to know what kind of tomato this is. Even if it had fruit that looked just like a particular breed's fruit, it would be a guess at best.

If the seeds were all supposed to be from Black Krim, then it's possible that one of them (or else all the others) were cross-pollinated, or that both groups were crossed by different tomatoes. It's also possible that it's a mutant.

It's also possibly a stray seed from another kind of tomato, which may have been mixed up with the Black Krim seeds.

Comment: I believe it is a stray seed because it is quite different form black krim. I even suspect it could be a determinate variety since it is more stocky with longer branches. It also bruises dark green if I touch the stem; https://imgur.com/TsDcu8C

Answer (score 3):

I think it has no variety/breed.

It looks very similar to "normal tomatoes". I think the seeds originated from cross pollination from other varieties. So it is an hybrid, but not stabilized. So we cannot classify at any variety.

"Normal tomatoes": such hybrids tend to have more the dominant genes, so they tend to look like normal tomatoes (smaller fruits). You may get a new variety, but it is not probable.

I have many of such "normal tomatoes": I but different varieties, but bees will cross-pollinate the varieties. Next year many plants will grow up (and I keep on a corner of my garden). It is incredible how "common" they will become. Parents are not recognizable.